# Why is it so hard to mirror a drive?

Tags: windows-7, mirroring

I appreciate any method that will work for my situation.

I have a 500 GB SSD drive with my operating system installed on it, which I have been using for years.  I bought another 500 GB SSD for the sake of backing up the first one.

What I have tried:

I went into my BIOS, changed to RAID mode, and tried to create a RAID1 for the drives.  It warned me it would wipe both drive, which I dont want, so I cancelled.

I went to the disk manager, I right clicked my new disk, and "Create mirrored volume" was grayed out.  I googled and eventually discovered that for whatever absurd reason, there is instead an "Add mirror" option from the source drive.  Which was also grayed out.  I continued to google and found that both drives must be dynamic, and that the destination drive must be unallocated.  This made the option available.

I clicked "Add mirror" to my main drive to copy it to my new drive, and it failed.  It says "All disks holding extents for a given volume must have the  same sector size, and the sector size must be valid."

I have no idea what a sector size is, or how to check it, or how to change it, and googling has led me nowhere.

I just want to backup this drive.

Comment: In order to do what you want, you would have to install Windows on an existing RAID, this cannot be done without reinstalling Windows.  As for the software RAID option, it appears the option isn't allowed, on the system disk as it's currently configured.

Comment: "I just want to backup this drive." Are you sure you only want to backup this drive, or do you need a live mirror on two disks? There's a major difference here. Creating a backup 'as of now' of your system is much simpler than setting up a RAID.

Comment: Do you just want to "copy" a drive manually a single/multiple times or do you actually want to use a RAID?

Comment: its hard to believe that computer science today can analyze AVL trees but cant copy paste my disk to a backup drive

Comment: as long as i can boot the OS from the copy and everything, i would be happy manually updating it instead of an actual RAID setup

Comment: Some useful links explaining why RAID is not the same thing as backup and should not be relied on : https://blog.storagecraft.com/5-reasons-raid-not-backup/   https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup   https://blog.open-e.com/why-raid-is-not-a-backup/

Comment: If your purpose is a simple backup, you're kind of wasting money using an SSD for that.  You pay a huge premium over a hard drive, don't require the speed, and a hard drive has longer data retention.  You could get a much larger hard drive for less money and have the capacity to make numerous full backups and incremental backups.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct from the comments above, you should forget the 'mirroring' you are trying to accomplish. It is attempting to make a LIVE copy of what happens on one disk to another disk in real-time.

What may get you what you want is to install Macrium Reflect (free for personal use) - from  https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree
and after making a blank partition on the second/new disk, make a system image backup of your system on the new disk.